# V4 Universal printer driver

Tags: v4-printer-driver

As you may know, MS V4 printer driver model is very relies on data files like .gpd and .ppt files.
In one hand, supposing a signed driver package, any changes in these files will break the driver sign. In the other hand regarding the need to create Universal Printer Drivers, it seems obvious that driver developers need some possibilities to change the content of these files otherwise tons of .gpd and .ppt files will be created to support very wide range of printer models and types.
Has any one an idea to overcome this issue?
Any help and answer is appreciated in advance.

Comment: [Good to read](http://universalprinterdriver.com/) regarding Universal Printer Driver concept.

Comment: [Universal V4 Printer Driver](https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX223749) on Citrix